# entry and the entry before the last

Tags: python

Im new to python.i have absolutly no idea how to solve this:

Extends the list with a While loop or For loop, so that the next entry is the sum of the last entry and the previous entry:

```
myListe = [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Pretty sure your list should start `[1,2,3,4,6]`, given the logic you elaborate and the values you expect in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deducing from your given values, you are starting out from

```
myListe = [1, 2, 3]
#          ^     ^
# index   -3    -1
```

and are supposed to add the last element and the one two before that.

This, you can achieve via:

```
while True:
    next_value = myListe[-3] + myListe[-1]
    if next_value > 1000:
        break
    myListe.append(next_value)
```

You can verify that the last value in the list is then in deed `872`.

```
myListe[-3:]
# [406, 595, 872]
```

Using some knowledge about built-in utils, slices and named assignments (Python >= 3.8), you can simplify the while loop:

```
while (next_value := sum(myListe[-3::2])) <= 1000:
    myListe.append(next_value)
```